# ¿Cómo se puede adaptar la expresión "the lion's share" al español?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

Acabo de leer en un tuit lo siguiente:

> Si te sorprende que en el presupuesto de un servicio basado en gran medida en los RRHH la parte del león sea la línea de personal, pocas cuentas anuales has auditado.

Me ha sorprendido el uso de la expresión inglesa *[the lion's share](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lion's_share)* traducida de forma literal. Según el diccionario de Oxford significa simplemente "la mayor parte" o "la parte principal". No tenía constancia de que la traducción literal se usara en español, y de hecho no encuentro registro de la misma ni en el DLE ni en el DAMER, ni de ninguna expresión similar. Lo más que encuentro es [una película argentina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_parte_del_le%C3%B3n) de 1978 que se llama precisamente así, y que no sé si se trata de una casualidad o si es que la expresión se usa así en Argentina.

Pregunto pues, ¿se usa *la parte del león* con este significado actualmente en alguna parte de Hispanoamérica? ¿O es que he encontrado un caso aislado? Si es un caso aislado, ¿existe alguna expresión en español que tenga de forma figurada el mismo significado?

Comment: Además que [el parte del león](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RzfwkpZ), hay [*la tajada del león*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="la+tajada+del+león"&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En el [**CORDE**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) se recogen varios usos de la expresión "la parte del león"; parece que el más antiguo es de Larra (*Buenas noches. Segunda carta de Fígaro a su corresponsal en París* - 1836) (negritas mías):

> Pero el tercero en discordia decidió la cuestión, y mientras que aquéllas y ésta se andaban representando la comedia de: ¿Quién ha de mandar en casa?, se adjudicó él a sí mismo la **parte del león** de la fábula.

Por otro lado, [**Etymonline**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lion#etymonline_v_9573) indica que el primer uso documentado de "lion's share" es de 1701:

> Lion's share "the greatest portion" is attested from 1701.

y [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion's_share) que:

> The lion's share is an idiomatic expression which refers to the major share of something. The phrase derives from the plot of a number of fables ascribed to Aesop and is used here as their generic title. There are two main types of story, which exist in several different versions.

Parece, por tanto, que "la parte del león" es una expresión correcta y válida en español, similar a la inglesa, por lo que no es necesario buscar una adaptación.

[**Aquí**](https://ei-talondeaquiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/la-parte-del-leon.html) mencionan que procede de una fábula de Fedro:

> Ya sabemos por experiencia que los poderosos siempre se quedan la mejor parte de las cosas y, muchas veces, no solo lo que les corresponde, sino también lo que les toca a los demás. Cuando eso ocurre, decimos que esa persona o institución se ha llevado la parte del león, que no es más que la parte mayor o más sustanciosa de los beneficios.
>
> La expresión proviene, como en muchas ocasiones, de una fábula, pero esta vez de Fedro (15-55 a. C.), el más antiguo de los fabulistas latinos, que en sus Fábulas esópicas presenta la siguiente historia:
>
> - Nunca es segura la alianza con un poderoso; esta fabulilla conﬁrma mi tesis. Una vaca, una cabrita, y una mansa oveja fueron al bosque como socios de un león. Una vez que hubieron cobrado un ciervo corpulento, hechas las partes, el león habló de la siguiente manera: “Yo tomo la primera parte porque me llamo león; la segunda me la dais por respeto a que soy vuestro socio; en tales circunstancias, puesto que soy más fuerte que vosotros, me corresponde la tercera; mal lo ha de pasar si alguno se atreve a tocar la cuarta”. De ese modo sólo la maldad se llevó la pieza entera (Phédre. Fables. París, 1969, 3ª ed. Text. y trad. por A. Brenot).
>
> Seguramente a esta fábula debemos también el adjetivo leonino (unas condiciones leoninas, un contrato leonino, etc.), que se aplica cuando las condiciones aplican solo a una de las partes.
>
> Referencias:
>
> - García Remiro, José Luis (2001). ¿Qué queremos decir cuando decimos...? Frases y dichos del lenguaje diario. Madrid: Alianza.

En [**este otro sitio**](https://mitosyleyendascr.com/fabulas/la-parte-del-leon/) reproducen una versión de la fábula, sin indicar el autor:

> La parte del león
>
> Cierto día, el león, cansado de cazar solo, invitó al oso y al zorro a acompafiarlo. Era poco frecuente que el orgulloso rey de la selva invitara a sus súbditos a acompafiarlo en una cacería, y el oso y el zorro se sintieron encantados y lisonjeados. En realidad, las cosas no habrían podido marchar mejor. .. por algún tiempo.
>
> Su suerte fue tan buena que, antes del anochecer, habían atrapado varios conejos, dos cabras y un ciervo. El león eligió para acampar un sitio próximo a su cubil y, pasándose la lengua por las quijadas, encargó al oso que repartiera sus presas.
>
> El bien dispuesto y honrado oso hizo inmediatamente lo que le había ordenado el león. En realidad, estaba tan atareado dividiendo lo cazado en tres partes iguales, y lo hacía con tanto cuidado, que no miro en dirección al león. Y fue una lástima, porque el león escarbaba el suelo, meneando la cola y enojándose cada vez más. Por fin, cuando el oso iba a terminar su tarea, el león le saltó encima, con un rugido, y lo despedazó. Después, más hambriento que nunca, miró con aire impaciente al zorro, que había estado contemplando la escena.
>
> -Ahora, veamos si sabes dividir las cosas de manera más razonable -ordenó-. Y hazlo con rapidez.
>
> En silencio, el zorro puso manos a la obra. En un abrir y cerrar de ojos, puso todas las presas que habían matado, inclusive al oso muerto, en una enorme pila. Para él, sólo se reservó un conejo pequeño.
>
> El león hizo con su maciza cabeza un ademán de aprobación.
>
> -Así concibo yo una división justa -dijo-. Eres un animal con sentido común.
>
> Cuando el zorro se disponía a abandonar el campamento con su raquítico conejo -porque había resuelto de pronto comérselo a solas-, el león volvió a hablarle.
>
> -Amigo Zorro -preguntó-. ¿Quién te enseñó a dividir las cosas tan bien?
>
> -Lo poco que sé, acabo de aprenderlo de mi difunto amigo el Oso -respondió el zorro.

Y [**aquí**](https://elrevisionista.blogspot.com/2010/04/la-parte-del-leon.html), comentando la película argentina citada, resaltan (negritas mías):

> Aristaran toma con toda la intención del mundo el título de una **fábula griega** <sup>**1**</sup> LA PARTE DEL LEÓN que habla sobre el egoísmo y la ley del mas fuerte, y que se usa para referirse a la tiranía y la indefensión del ciudadano de a pie ante el poderoso.

<sup>**1**</sup> [**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayo_Julio_Fedro) indica que Fedro fue un fabulista **romano**.